# Isset function in php 5.4.16 is not funcitoning

Tags: php, forms, submit, isset

Under the php version

```
PHP 5.2.4 (cli) (built: Oct 16 2007 16:54:49)
Copyright (c) 1997-2007 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007 Zend Technologies
```

The function isset is working fine, the below is the snippet from the script.

```
<form name="fff" method=post style="font-size:12pt;">

 <tr height="24">
          <td height="24" width="105"> <p align="left" style="margin-left:10;"><b><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:10pt;"><?php echo $Agent_03; ?></span></font></b></p> </td>
          <td height="24" width="40">
            <p align="center">
              <input type="text" name="CosHour_03" value="<?php echo $AtdH_03; ?>" style="font-weight:normal; font-size:10pt; color:rgb(102,102,102); text-align:center; on" maxlength="2" size="2">
            </p>
          </td>
          <td height="24" width="5"> <p align="center"><b><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:10pt;">:</span></font></b></p> </td>
          <td height="24" width="40">
            <p align="center">
              <input type="text" name="CosMine_03" value="<?php echo $AtdM_03; ?>" style="font-weight:normal; font-size:10pt; color:rgb(102,102,102); text-align:center; on" maxlength="2" size="2">
            </p>
          </td>
          <td height="24" width="105">
            <p align="right">
              <input type="text" name="Cs_03" value="" style="font-weight:normal; font-size:10pt; color:rgb(102,102,102); on" maxlength="12" size="12">
            </p>
          </td>
          <td height="24" width="185">
            <p align="left"><input type="text" name="CnsCoe_03" value="<?php echo $CleCoe_03; ?>" style="font-weight:normal; font-size:10pt; color:rgb(102,102,102); on" maxlength="24" size="24">
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>

<p align="center" ;">
        <input type="submit" name="ReportCons_Submit" value="SUBMIT" style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:14; color:rgb(32,46,125); letter-spacing:4; text-align:center; background-color:rgb(204,204,204); margin-left:0;" size="200">
      </p>

</form>


<?php

if ( isset( $ReportCons_Submit)) {

          $alertmessage   = "";
          $successmessage = "";
          $strCountry     = strtoupper( $Country);
          $strLocation    = strtoupper( $Location);
          $strFixedDate   = date("Ymd", strtotime(date("Y")."-".$CnsMonth."-".$CnsDay));
.
.
.
.
?>
```

The same thing is not working in the recent php version.

```
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr  4 2016 07:13:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

If we click Submit button, i Dont feel the control gets in to if statement.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: can you show where the variable $ReportCons_Submit is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset` works, but `$ReportCons_Submit` doesn't exist.

Use

`if (isset($_POST['ReportCons_Submit'])) {...}`

The 'problem' is caused by [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) which are removed in PHP 5.4.0 (deprecated in PHP 5.3.0).

Comment: HI @panther $_POST works fine, it gets into if statement, But the variables aren't getting declared. I am getting the below errors. 
Notice: Undefined variable: 
Notice: Undefined variable: 
Notice: Undefined variable: 
Notice: Undefined variable:

Comment: No variables aren't defined which going from form. `$Country`, `$Location` and others aren't defined too - not in PHP code, nor in your form. For example, value from input with `name=CosHour_03` will be in $_POST['CosHour_03'], etc. If `$Location` come from another source (not from form), check, if exists. `$Location = isset($Location) ? strtoupper( $Location) : 'default value if isn't defined';`

Comment: Those are defined earlier in the same script, I didnt produce here the entire script, This php file will open with text boxes and submit button, we will feed in some value, Press submit, then it should get into if statement and feed the values into database. That process works good in earlier versionof PHP, but the same directory structure we have in the new php version box, it is throwing errors when $_POST function added to it.

Comment: @sabarishjackson: what errors? Undefined variable can't be caused by adding (correct) `$_POST['key']` to post variables due to removed register globals.

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (isset($_POST['ReportCons_Submit'])){}`. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
if(!empty($ReportCons_Submit)){

}
```

instead of

```
if(isset($ReportCons_Submit)){


}
```

Comment: Why trying that? Why should `!empty` works when `isset` fails?

Comment: @panther Because  !empty() will evaluate to true only if there is something other than null, false, 0, or empty string while isset will quack if your variable has empty data like empty string.

Comment: But the question isn't about `null` or other values. It's about removed register globals in PHP 5.4.0. `ReportCons_Submit` is name of submit input, it can't be `null`, `false`, etc., its value is _SUBMIT_.